# Javascript - how to get a float value from an HTML input?

Tags: javascript, input, floating-point

I am experiencing some problem retrieving float numbers value with JavaScript from HTML  by clicking on a button and then process them into a PHP file.

The HTML part is inside a table (maybe is usefull for extra info):

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
   <!-- some other <td> here -->
    <td>
    <img name="clickImage" style="position: relative;  margin: auto;" src="myImage.png" onClick="fooFloat()">
    </td>
    <td>
    <input id="toAngleH" maxlength="6" size="6" type="text" value="" style="background-color: #ffff;"/>
        <br>
    <input id="toAngleV" maxlength="6" size="6" type="text"value="" style="background-color: #ffff;"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And my Javascript function fooFloat() is the following:

```
function fooFloat()
{    
  //doesn't work
  var $angleH = parseFloat(document.getElementById("toAngleH").value);
  var $angleV = parseFloat(document.getElementById("toAngleV").value);

  //doesn't work
  //var $angleH = $("#toAngleH").val();
  //var $angleV = $("#toAngleV").val();

  $("#content").load("file.php",{ toAngleH: angleH, toAngleV: angleV });
}
```

In the PHP file the values are retrieved as always with the

```
isset($_POST["string"])
```

function which works fine for integer numbers, but seems I cannot process the float values into the Javascript function.

I don't know where I am wrong.
Thank you in advance for your help.

**EDIT:**

I finally solved the problem. I was missing an apostrophe in the PHP file...

Bye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [http post request](http://christianalfoni.github.io/javascript/2014/01/20/sending-json.html) the data is [serialized/encoded](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) to string and posted to server. Now it's server responsibility to parse these data correctly.
As far as Javascript is concerned you are retrieving it correctly . However i think you have a typo where you storing the value in `$angleH` but using `angleH` ($ omitted).
You may wish to check network headers through [debugger network tab](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network) to see what data is posted to the server.

```
var val = document.getElementById("toAngleV").value//string value
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try passing the number as a string and parsing it on the server side? I'd imagine there is some kind of issue with the point or comma. You could maybe try replacing those characters before posting and then replacing then back on the server before type changing.

Comment: Hi jpbourbon, I tried to use the toString() method but it neither works.